# Revoke access to delete a specific Account record type

Tags: apex, trigger, account, record-type, delete

I have this apex trigger that revokes access to users from deleting all Accounts. I was wondering how to improve it to ignore or allow certain record type. The use case is, I want to allow users to delete 'prospect' records but not allow them to delete 'client' accounts. I'm not a developer and this is a pet project - I got this far from a code a found online for revoking access from deleting email-messages.

```
global class PreventClientAccountDelete{
    public static void PreventClientAccountDelete(Account [] pAccount, Account [] pOldAccount) {

        //Client Account deletion is only allowed for administrator

        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;
        for(Account currentAccount : pOldAccount) {

            //Check if current user is not a system administrator
            if(profileName !='System Administrator' && profileName !='Integration Administrator'){
                currentAccount.addError('You can not delete a Client Account, please contact your Salesforce Administrator');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Kevin,

You want to obtain the recordtype involved first, you can do it this way

```
Id prospectRecordTypeId = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Prospect').getRecordTypeId();
```

Then, you can add the following clause to the if statement

`currentAccount.RecordTypeId != prospectRecordTypeId`

Your code will end up like this

```
Id prospectRecordTypeId = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Prospect').getRecordTypeId();

String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;
for(Account currentAccount : pOldAccount) {

    //Check if current user is not a system administrator
    if(currentAccount.RecordTypeId != prospectRecordTypeId && profileName !='System Administrator' && profileName !='Integration Administrator'){
        currentAccount.addError('You can not delete a Client Account, please contact your Salesforce Administrator');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an extra if clause, to check the record being deleted is not client record type.

```
public static void PreventClientAccountDelete(Account [] pAccount, Account [] pOldAccount) {

    //Client Account deletion is only allowed for administrator

    Id clientRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('client').getRecordTypeId();
    String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;
    for(Account currentAccount : pOldAccount) {

        //Check if current user is not a system administrator
        if(profileName !='System Administrator' && profileName !='Integration Administrator'){

            if(clientRecordTypeId == currentAccount.RecordTypeId){
                currentAccount.addError('You can not delete a Clieant Account, please contact your Salesforce Administrator');
            }                

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: One should not put a describe call in a loop. There is an associated CPU cost scales with the number of record types and fields an object has.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox.  I never thought to describe calls are so resource intensive. I remember there was a limit on a number of describe calls, but they were lifted a few years back.

Comment: Yes, they were made unlimited, but they still cost CPU time, so we should always cache results for performance.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is working great. Should I be worried about the CPU cost?

Comment: @KevinK I  updated code to optimize the performance.

Comment: Id clientRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('client').getRecordTypeId() I'm not sure if this is working as intended. I get this error "There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help." as opposed the message in the Apex code.